# Remove excel duplicated with ignoring case - Python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a excel file with this data

```
Python
C++
Pandas
python
PHP
```

and I want to remove duplicated with ignoring case, my code :

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx', header=None)
data = data.drop_duplicates()
data.to_excel('sts.xlsx', index=False, header=False)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx', header=None)
data = data.iloc[data.iloc[:, 0].str.lower().drop_duplicates().index]
data.to_excel('sts.xlsx', index=False, header=False)
```